# Can you simplify this expression?

Tags: calculus, probability

This is a Bayes formula incorporating 2 random variables. The final expression seems a bit tricky to simplify the exponents and I'm still not so confident with my algebra (pardon me ;)). Can you have a go ?

From here :

$
\frac{\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}(y-1)^2}}{\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}(y+1)^2} + \frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}(y-1)^2}}
$

To there :

$
\frac{1}{1 + e^{-2y}}
$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint**

Multiply by

\begin{equation}
\frac{2\sqrt{2\pi}}{2\sqrt{2\pi}} \frac{\mathrm{e}^{\frac{1}{2}(y-1)^2}}{\mathrm{e}^{\frac{1}{2}(y-1)^2}}.
\end{equation}

Comment: Thx, gonna toy with it a bit :)

Answer (score 0):

Note that $\exp\{x\} = e^x$.

\begin{align}
&\frac{\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\left\{-\frac{1}{2}(y-1)^2\right\}}{\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\left\{-\frac{1}{2}(y+1)^2\right\} + \frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\left\{-\frac{1}{2}(y-1)^2\right\}}\\\\ &\qquad=
\frac{\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\left\{-\frac{1}{2}(y-1)^2\right\}}{\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\left(\exp\left\{-\frac{1}{2}(y+1)^2\right\} + \exp\left\{-\frac{1}{2}(y-1)^2\right\}\right)}\\\\
&\qquad = \frac{\exp\left\{-\frac{1}{2}(y-1)^2\right\}}{\exp\left\{-\frac{1}{2}(y+1)^2\right\} + \exp\left\{-\frac{1}{2}(y-1)^2\right\}}\\\\
&\qquad = \frac{1}{\exp\left\{-\frac{1}{2}(y+1)^2+\frac{1}{2}(y-1)^2\right\}+1}\\\\
&\qquad = \frac{1}{\exp\left\{-\frac{1}{2}(y^2+2y+1)+\frac{1}{2}(y^2-2y+1)\right\}+1}\\\\
&\qquad = \frac{1}{\exp\left\{\frac{1}{2}(-y^2-2y-1+y^2-2y+1)\right\}+1}\\\\
&\qquad = \frac{1}{\exp\left\{\frac{1}{2}(-4y)\right\}+1}\\\\
&\qquad = \frac{1}{e^{-2y}+1}
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

$$
\frac{\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}(y-1)^2}}{\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}(y+1)^2} + \frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}(y-1)^2}}
$$
$$= \frac{\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\ \cdot\ e^{-\frac{1}{2}(y-1)^2}}{\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\ \cdot\ \left(e^{-\frac{1}{2}(y+1)^2} + e^{-\frac{1}{2}(y-1)^2}\right)}$$
$$= \frac{e^{-\frac{1}{2}(y-1)^2}}{e^{-\frac{1}{2}(y+1)^2} + e^{-\frac{1}{2}(y-1)^2}}$$
$$= \frac{e^{-\frac{1}{2}(y-1)^2}}{e^{-\frac{1}{2}(y+1)^2} + e^{-\frac{1}{2}(y-1)^2}}\cdot\frac{e^{\frac{1}{2}(y-1)^2}}{e^{\frac{1}{2}(y-1)^2}}$$
$$= \frac{1}{e^{-\frac{1}{2}(y+1)^2}e^{\frac{1}{2}(y-1)^2} + 1}$$
$$= \frac{1}{e^{\frac{1}{2}((y-1)^2-(y+1)^2)} + 1}$$
$$= \frac{1}{e^{\frac{1}{2}(-4y)} + 1}$$
$$= \frac{1}{e^{-2y} + 1}$$
Done.